# loading/streaming a file into a buffer/buffers

Tags: c#, buffer, filestream, streamreader, seek

I have been trying for a couple of days now to load a file in chunks to allow the user to use very large (GB) files and still keep the speed of the program. Currently i have the following code:

```
using (FileStream filereader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filereader))
    {
      while (toRead > 0 && (bytesread = reader.Read(buffer, offset, toRead)) > 0)
      {
        toRead -= bytesread;
        offset += bytesread;
      }

      if (toRead > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();

      foreach (var item in buffer)
      {
        temporary = temporary += item.ToString();
      }
      temporary.Replace("\n", "\n" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Below are the declarations to avoid any confusion (hopefully):

```
  const int Max_Buffer = 5000;
  char[] buffer = new char[Max_Buffer];
  int bytesread;
  int toRead = 5000;
  int offset = 0;
```

At the moment the program reads in 5000 bytes of the text file, then processes the bytes into a string which i then pass into a stringreader so i can take the information i want.

My problem at the moment is that the buffer can stop halfway through a line so when I take my data in the stringreader class it brings up index/length errors.

What i need is to know how to either seek back in the array to find a certain set of characters that signify the start of a line and then only return the data before that point for processing to a string.

Another issue after sorting the seeking back problem is how would i keep the data i didnt want to process and bring in more data to fill the buffer.

I hope this is explained well, i know i can sometimes be confusing hope someone can help.

Comment: break the top while on every line break? The same as using ReadLine() Then you would only have to seek forward. You could use a string builder to store any temporary lines (lines over Max_buffer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of **reader.ReadLine()** instead of **reader.Read()** in your loop

```
buffer=reader.ReadLine();
bytesread = buffer.Length*2;//Each charcter is unicode and equal to 2 bytes
```

You can then check on the whether (toRead - bytesread)<0.